# Access to undeclared static property: User::$rules in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function update($id)
  {
    $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);
        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            $user = User::find($id);
            $user->update($input);
            return Redirect::route('users.show', $id);
        }
return Redirect::route('users.edit', $id)
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
  }
```

this is what the code i am having, when I attempt to update a record it shows the following error message. Access to undeclared static property: User::$rules

the user model as follows

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

 use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

 /**
  * The database table used by the model.
  *
  * @var string
  */
 protected $table = 'users';

 /**
  * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
  *
  * @var array
  */
 protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

Comment: What happens if instead of `User::$rules` you try to use `User::getFacadeRoot()->rules`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you have a property in your User model like this:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    public $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    );

}
```

This is a class instance property, but you’re trying to access it statically (the error messages tells you such).

Simply add the `static` keyword to the property:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    public static $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    );

}
```